# Using JS to toggle between two HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, css, grid

Looking to make an interactive landing page, and I would like visitors to click on a HTML element, which then disappears and is replaced by another.

I've included the code below for your review, and the codepen link: https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/pMrWKw

The issue is that the toggle does not work and after multiple clicks both h4 and p tags completely disappear. I've tried switching where the place the .hide class in the CSS (which for some reason makes a difference, and I don't understand why).

```js
const switchElements = document.querySelectorAll('.switch');

for(const switchElement of switchElements) {
    switchElement.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
       e.target.classList.toggle('hide');
       e.target.nextSibling.classList.toggle('hide')
    })
}
```

```css
.main{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
}   
.three-points {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr);
    i {
        display:grid;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    h4 {
        display:grid;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: start;
        border:solid;
    }
  }
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="three-points">
     <i class="fab fa-google fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">SEO Optomized</h4><p class="switch hide">Utilizing best practices to ensure page is ranked appopriately</p>
      <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">Responsive Design</h4><p class="switch hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At autem culpa possimus facere. Recusandae.</p>
      <i class="fa fa-window-maximize fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">Elegant Themes</h4><p class="switch hide">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt quis consequatur asperiores. Odit, voluptates nihil.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ok so the issue is that the JS is looking for the nextSibling. After the first click, how can I use an if function to remove .hide from the **previousSibling**?

---

Comment: can you please explain the workflow related to which element gonna hide

Comment: The <h4> and <p> will switch back and forth. Clicking one will hide it, and display the other

Comment: While you're trying to achieve this with javascript, I actually have a proposal... use radio button with css?

Comment: Hi Leo, if you build it, they will come. 

Present me some code and I'll be interested in reviewing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your CSS. The biggest problem is that the parentheses are unbalanced, so the .hide definition gets missed. Secondary issue is that the nested definitions are not CSS. They look like less or sass.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the logic below to hide/show the **h** and **p** tag back and forth.
Also to toggle on click event in **p** tag

```js
var switchElements = document.getElementsByClassName("switch");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < switchElements.length; i++) {
  switchElements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    if(this.classList.contains("hide")){
          // hide on <p> tag click
          this.style.display = "none";
          this.previousSibling.style.display = "block";
    }else{
          this.style.display = "none";
          var content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
          }
    }

    

  });
}
```

```css
.main{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
}  
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.three-points {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr);
  i {
      display:grid;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  h4 {
      display:grid;
      align-content: center;
      justify-content: start;
      border:solid;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="three-points">
     <i class="fab fa-google fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">SEO Optomized</h4><p class="switch hide">Utilizing best practices to ensure page is ranked appopriately</p>
      <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">Responsive Design</h4><p class="switch hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At autem culpa possimus facere. Recusandae.</p>
      <i class="fa fa-window-maximize fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">Elegant Themes</h4><p class="switch hide">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt quis consequatur asperiores. Odit, voluptates nihil.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to the fact that you are adding the event listener to all elements immediately. Instead, try adding and removing the event listener dynamically as required. You should add the `.hide` class to all elements in HTML except the first (default shown) element. I have tested the below:

```
const switchElements = document.querySelectorAll('.switch');
let activeElement = 0

let cycleElements = function() {
    switchElements[activeElement].removeEventListener('click', cycleElements)
    switchElements[activeElement].classList.add('hide')

    if (activeElement >= switchElements.length - 1) {
        activeElement = 0
    } else {
        activeElement++
    }

    switchElements[activeElement].addEventListener('click', cycleElements)
    switchElements[activeElement].classList.remove('hide')
}

switchElements[activeElement].addEventListener('click', cycleElements)
```

Add classes like below:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="three-points">
    <i class="fab fa-google fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">SEO Optomized</h4><p class="switch hide">Utilizing best practices to ensure page is ranked appopriately</p>
    <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch hide">Responsive Design</h4><p class="switch hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At autem culpa possimus facere. Recusandae.</p>
    <i class="fa fa-window-maximize fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch hide">Elegant Themes</h4><p class="switch hide">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt quis consequatur asperiores. Odit, voluptates nihil.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT START:

Not sure if I want to start another question for this but I would like to know why moving the CSS class .hide breaks the below code:

Thanks,

EDIT END:

Figured it out.

Had to add another Eventlistener that listened for a click on the

tag. Code is below:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">

<div class="three-points">

  <i class="fa fa-google fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">SEO Optomized</h4><p class="back hide">Utilizing best practices to ensure page is ranked appopriately</p>
  <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">Responsive Design</h4><p class="back hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At autem culpa possimus facere. Recusandae.</p>
  <i class="fa fa-window-maximize fa-5x"></i><h4 class="switch">Elegant Themes</h4><p class="back hide">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt quis consequatur asperiores. Odit, voluptates nihil.</p>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {


    margin-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);



    .three-points {

        .hide {

            display: none;
        }


        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr);

            i {
                display:grid;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            h4 {
                display:grid;
                align-content: center;
                justify-content: start;
                border:solid;
            }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
const switchElements = document.querySelectorAll('.switch');

for(const switchElement of switchElements) {
    switchElement.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        e.target.classList.add('hide');
        e.target.nextSibling.classList.remove('hide');

    })
}

const backElements = document.querySelectorAll('.back');

for (const backs of backElements) {
    backs.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.classList.add('hide');
        e.target.previousSibling.classList.remove('hide');
    })
}
```

Comment: Why you need to bind so many event listener when it can be done using single listener event

Comment: I agree, I would prefer to do it in one. However, I ran your code and it did not work as desired. Can you confirm your code is working?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wouldn't say this is a legit answer, since I'm not solving this question with JS.

But reality is, there's always multiple ways to solve (or you might call it a hack) a problem.

This is the approach I use quite a few times on production, and doesn't require a single line of javascript.

I'm not reuse your code, but write my own to keep it as simple as it is, but the idea is easy enough to apply on your case.

if you want to keep them opened, the radio can be changed to checkbox.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input:checked ~div {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<label for="radio1">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="toggler">
  toggle 1
  <div>
    this is the first content
  </div>
</label>

<label for="radio2">
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="toggler">
  toggle 2
  <div>
    this is the second content
  </div>
</label>

<label for="radio3">
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="toggler">
  toggle 3
  <div>
    this is the third content
  </div>
</label>
```